# How to replace a button text in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my app code:

```
<li class="ui-block-e">
  <a href="#login" data-transition="slide" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" id="UserLoginButtonP5" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-btn-up-b" data-inline="true">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">Login</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

jQuery replace code:

```
$("#UserLoginButtonP1").html("<span class='ui-btn-inner'><span class='ui-btn-text'>Logout</span></span>");
```

How do I replace Login to Logout text?

Comment: there is no element with ID of UserLoginButtonP1 in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var test = $("#UserLoginButtonP5").html();
    test = test.replace('Login', 'Logout');
    $("#UserLoginButtonP5").html(test);
```

Working Demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgTcM/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `on()` function instead

```
$(document)​​​​​​.on('click', '"#UserLoginButtonP5"',function(){
   $(this).find('span').find('span').text("Logout");
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VFrSK/)

Comment: Well this is one of the solution to your question. Its up to you to make it work for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If you want to replace the button text, when click the button means the given below code will work.

```
$("#btn1")​​​​​​.click(function(){
   $(this).val("Logout");
});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/9kTjH/)

In your scenario, you want to change the text of `span`, so you can use `span` *css class name* as click event like,

```
$(".ui-btn-text").bind('click',function(){
    $(this).html("Logout");
});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/9kTjH/1/)

(or)

you want to do this in `a` click event, the given below code will work,

```
$("#UserLoginButtonP5").bind('click',function(){
    $("#UserLoginButtonP5 .ui-btn-text").html("Logout");
    //$("#UserLoginButtonP5 .ui-btn-text").text("Logout"); ('text' will be work also)
});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/9kTjH/3/)